# USB Device is not authorized for usage

Tags: 20.04, security

I am using the newest Ubuntu 20.04, and all software were updated.

After installation of system, U disk can be used without any problem. After installation of many other software, U disk can not be recognized. I am sure the driver was installed. When I run `lsusb`, I can find the usb disk

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2
```

When I run `dmesg`, it shows

```
[241620.374470] usb 1-1.3: Device is not authorized for usage
[241637.411899] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

I edited the `org.freedesktop.devicekit.udisks.policy`, change `allow_any` to yes and still not work!

Later, I found the problem is that usbguard blocks the usb-device.

Find out the id of device by `usbguard list-devices` and use `usbguard allow-device XX`.  But how can it work automatically?

Comment: Try some of the solutions here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533198/usb-devices-not-authorized-for-usage-after-debian-upgrade

Answer (score 9):

If you have [usbguard](https://usbguard.github.io/) and it blocks devices that you want to use, you can use the `usbguard` tool to add them to allowed list. Run `usbguard` and you should get some fairly clear instructions.

```sh
usbguard list-devices # optionally --blocked
```

Should give you a listing of connected devices and whether they are allowed or blocked. You can pick an id ([first number](https://github.com/USBGuard/usbguard/issues/334#issuecomment-704891576)) and run e.g.

```sh
usbguard allow-device -p 17    # allow-device [OPTIONS] <'id' | rule>
```

> `-p`, `--permanent` Make the decision permanent. A device specific allow rule will be appended to the current policy.

and should see the change in journal:

```
kernel: usb 1-1: authorized to connect
```

Usbguard is meant to block all devices hotplugged after system boot. To make persistent changes, you can add rules to `/etc/usbguard/rules.conf`. You can generate config from current rules with `usbguard generate-policy`.

So, to see what's changed between them, you can:

```
usbguard generate-policy | sudo diff - /etc/usbguard/rules.conf
```

And to overwrite the rules file with current run:

```
usbguard generate-policy | sudo tee /etc/usbguard/rules.conf
```

You can also edit the rules manually and copy across machines etc.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the `usbguard` package by:

```
sudo apt autopurge usbguard
```

and reboot.

Comment: I remove the usbguard and it works. Thank you!